# Can I design a button like the one given in pic using Kivy?

Tags: python, button, user-interface, kivy

I need white background for the buttons and a picture on the left. And also an arrow mark on the left like in the picture. I also want to do rounded corners for the button. Are the above things possible with Kivy? And also how di I do it. Give me an example or something! Thanks!
[image]

Comment: On SO it is better to ask how to do something than to ask if it possible.

Comment: @brousch Not really, IMO. The best way to get a positive response is to show what you've already tried.

Comment: Surely the best way is to do both of the above!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are the above things possible with Kivy?

The answer is simply 'yes'. Do you have a specific context that you're having trouble with?

You simply need to create your own widget rule that displays things the way you want. It might start as something like

```
<YourRule@BoxLayout>:
    text: 'something'  # define a property to hold the button text, 
                       # could also be done in python
    Image:
        size_hint_x: None
        width: self.height  # make it square
        source: 'whatever'
    Label:
        text_size: self.size  # the text wrapping bounds
        text: root.text
        halign: 'left'
    Image:
        size_hint_x: None
        width: dp(10)
        source: 'right_arrow.png'  # assuming you have a picture of the button arrow
                                   # you could also draw one manually with kivy canvas instructions
```